# Show/hide element according to the selected option

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to hide the speech response **element**, if the user selects the **Tamil** language from the drop down, but if the user selects **English**, the speech response element should be hidden.

It doesn't work, I don't know why. Please, give me a suggestion on what's wrong with my code.

Here is my code:

```js
function Speech(say) {
  if ('speechSynthesis' in window && talking) {
    $('#clitamilhide').hide();

    var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(say);
    speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
  }

}

var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(ans);
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

```html
<select name="language_" id="langu" class="selectpicker form-control form-control-sm" style="width: 300px;  margin-top: 125px;">
  <option value="English">
    English
  </option>
  <option value="Tamil">
    Tamil
  </option>
</select>
```

In line

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(ans);
```

the backend response will be used and this response goes to the `speech()` function responding an output as voice.

The main problem is I want to hide the Tamil option tag value inside the function `speech(say)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description ***(if I got it right)***, here's a sample you can customize according to your needs.

Change the select tag's option and you'll see, that the sample hides/shows the example element according to the currently selected option.

---

Quick rundown:

- When the user runs your site/web app, we check the currently selected option, if it's **English**, we are okay, if it's not, we **hide** the "speech response" element *(whatever element will be your final implementation)*
- An event listener will be also attached to the select tag to detect, when the user changes the current option. If it's **English**, again, we show the "speech response", if it's not, we're gonna **hide it**.

```js
// hides the speech response
function showSpeechResponse() {
  $('.response').show();
}

// showes the speech response
function hideSpeechResponse() {
  $('.response').hide();
}

// checks what's the currently selected option
function checkSelectedOption() {
  var element = $('.selectpicker');
  
  switch ($(element).val()) {
    case 'English':
      showSpeechResponse();
      break;
      
    case 'Tamil':
      hideSpeechResponse();
      break;
  }
}

// check the initially selected option
checkSelectedOption();

// when the user selects another option, check the selected option
$('.selectpicker').on('change', checkSelectedOption);

/* your own code here ...
function speech(say) {
  if ('speechSynthesis' in window && talking) {
    $('#clitamilhide').hide();

    var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(say);
    speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
  }
}

var ans = 'The answer';
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(ans);
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
*/
```

```css
.selectpicker {
  /*margin-top: 125px;*/
  width: 300px;
}

.response {
  margin-top: 15px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="language_" id="langu" class="selectpicker form-control form-control-sm">
  <option value="English">English</option>
  <option value="Tamil" >Tamil</option>
</select>

<div class="response">Speech Response</div>
```

---

#### Note

*I hope you wanted something like this, **at least a starting point to use**, if I'm mistaken, please, tell me and we're gonna figure out a better solution.*